# CPU usage in a VM is over 100%

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, cpu-usage

I have installed an `Ubuntu server 16.04` in a VM from [vultr](https://www.vultr.com/pricing/) (my plan is 2 CPU, 4GB RAM) and I noticed today in the admin panel that the CPU usage the last month is over 100% (currently is in 103%).

In the server a web server is deployed (`Apache`) and some small `WordPress` sites are hosted.

How is possible to use over 100% than you have? Is this a sign that I should upgrade to a higher plan with more resources?

[image]

Comment: Depends how that data is gathered. If it's based on load average, it could mean something like that you're using half of each CPU/core, or it could mean one's maxed out and the other's mostly idle. Take a look at `top`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you should be worried or not depends on what the data represents. If it's per cpu then you have a "100%" for every cpu. Say, if the server it's a quad processor you could have a total load of 400%.

That said, it's possible to have an overload or spikes because the processes are putted on queue. Here you ave a simple but good reading

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2009/07/31/understanding-load-averages

> A single-core CPU is like a single lane of traffic. Imagine you are a
>   bridge operator ... sometimes your bridge is so busy there are cars
>   lined up to cross. You want to let folks know how traffic is moving on
>   your bridge. A decent metric would be how many cars are waiting at a
>   particular time. If no cars are waiting, incoming drivers know they
>   can drive across right away. If cars are backed up, drivers know
>   they're in for delays.

Before upgrading i would check *top* and optimize apache and php processes.

Comment: Just found this question. Was trying to get an answer for a load over 100% on a pegged CPU system where if it were per core it would have been near 400% but it's rather about 125%. Trying to understand the difference between 125% and 100%.

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple CPU then 100% usage might show information for one CPU only, so in your case maximum should be 200%.

If your sites are loading fast and responsive and you do not anticipate increase of visitors - no need to upgrade right now.